# Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type Database, key "DatabaseConnection"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, database-connection, enterprise-library-5

I am using a class library with an app.config and using the dll reference of this library in my web project and I am getting the error shown in the title. Here is the code in my class library and app.config

```
public List<EppActualsBEO> GetEppActualsList(String requestId)
{
List<EppActualsBEO> listitem = new List<EppActualsBEO>();
try
{
Database database = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>("DatabaseConnection");
command = database.GetSqlStringCommand(query.GetEPPredictionActualsQuery(requestId));
dr = database.ExecuteReader(command);
}
catch (Exception err)
{
throw err;
}
finally
{
dr.Close();
}
return listitem;
}
```

and

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral"/>
    </configSections>
    <dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="DatabaseConnection"/>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DatabaseConnection"
              connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=****)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME= ****)));User Id= ****;Password= ****;Persist Security Info=True;"
              providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was related to my App.Config configuration file.
I used the Enterprise Library Configuration tool, then open the App.Config of my project in the Enterprise Library Configuration tool realized default settings and saved the file, and it worked properly.